# Best way to do a setting in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

With settings, I've always had some const variable in a file somewhere.  Is it possible to create a new config file with all my settings for my website?  IE:

```
CONST imagePrefixPath = "http://img.domain.com/"
```

Is the sort of thing I want to store and use all over my web code

Comment: ...and what's wrong with the `web.config`? (e.g. [appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx) coupled with [retrieval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx))

Comment: @Brad, nothing, but I don't know how to add custom rules? Where do they go etc?  I'm new to all this, please forgive my ignorance!

Comment: See my comment, updated it with MSDN references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the appSettings in the web.config instead:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="imagePrefixPath" value="http://img.domain.com/" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then access it in code access the [appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx) variables using [OpenWebConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456.aspx)

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
String imagePath = config.AppSettings.Settings["imagePrefixPath"] + "myimage.jpg";
```

Comment: Why OpenWebConfiguration() as opposed to ConfigurationManager?

Comment: In web.config I've got: <appSettings configSource="app.config" /> (installed by YAF), can I merge that file?

Comment: @anon: Considering Tom's use of the configSource, I would say it's a better approach (though I suppose it doesn't matter). @TomGullen: It should be fine, it's saying those keys are in another file.

Comment: I get a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when using that code

Comment: @TomGullen: Sorry, use `"~"` in the OpenWebConfiguration, otherwise it uses the framework's config.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Settings file (add a new item=> settings file), which will also create a strongly typed class with the same names and values you set inside it.

Comment: This is pretty neat.  You've taught me something new!